# NHibernate HiLo on column other that primary key

Tags: nhibernate

Anyone come across a way of implementing a hilo type solution on a column other than the primary key. Have a column like jobno that i don't want to be the primary key (as using guidcomb and happy with it) and need to have a sequential numbers for it and don't want to hit the db to get the next value.

Comment: Can you not just give it an Identity in the DB, you would get the # when you commit the record.

Comment: Thanks @Phil, but "don't want to hit the db to get the next value" Thats the point of the HiLo

Comment: And I don't know why you don't want to hit the database. What benefit to you get from not hitting the DB?

Comment: Being able to initially create my entities and have access to the value prior to it being persisted.

Comment: You don't need to share the JobNo with other entities. You reference them with the PK not the JobNo. No other entity should have the JobNo so I still fail to see why this can't be generated on commit.

Comment: Phil. No offense, but the question was not "should I do this". Appreciate your time to respond. But I have services that need that number before it is persisted. I have found this in the interim: http://www.sharpthoughts.org/?p=32 Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: Chev - No offence, but if you can't answer questions, you can't expect help. Other services needing that # suggests you're using the Job# as the identifier, so you may as well make it the PK.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything that works "out of the box", but you could create an instance of NHibernate.Id.TableHiLoGenerator (which NHibernate uses to generate id values) and use it to generate values. However you still need to manually set the generated value for the entity.

You could also do your own generator by inheriting from TableHiLoGenerator:

```
public class MyHiLoGenerator : TableHiLoGenerator
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    public MyHiLoGenerator(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        Configure(NHibernateUtil.Int64, new Dictionary<string, string> {{"table", "mytable"}, {"column", "mycolumn"}}, ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory).Dialect);
    }

    public long NextValue()
    {
        return (long) Generate((ISessionImplementor) _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(), null);
    }
}
```

This is just a quick example which isn't tested at all, but it still shows the idea how TableHiLoGenerator can be used. I used something like this for generating HiLo values myself.